# php Curl vs postman giving different results on error

Tags: php, curl

I have a php curl script that returns the results of a get the run as a command from another process.  The code is:

```
<?php
$arr = getopt("f:");
$url = $arr['f'];
$ch = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 if (curl_errno($ch)) {
  echo curl_error($ch);
 } else {
  echo $result;
 }
 curl_close($ch);
 ?>
```

When I do a api get request for a specific url with curl that gives a 400 error, curl_error($ch) is "The requested URL returned error: 400 Bad Request"

When I run the same request in postman, I get a json reply such as: {"result_ok":false,"code":400,"message":"Invalid Email: xxxxxxxxxx@ail.com (POST)"}.

How can I get the json returned in the curl request?  If I echo the $result when there is an error condition, it is null.

Comment: Did you try `CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0`?  It should return something, maybe the JSON.

Comment: I had tried tried that using false and it did not change, but maybe something did not update.  I used your suggestion and it worked.  Please post the suggestion as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [CURLOPT_FAILONERROR explained](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FAILONERROR.html):

> fail the request if the HTTP code returned is equal to or larger than 400. **The default action would be to return the page normally, ignoring that code**.

`CURLOPT_FAILONERROR` is `false` by default so either remove it or set it:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);
```